# including Sass-cache folder on live site

Tags: sass

Hey guys I am new to `SASS`. 
Now my project includes the `sass cache folder`. The point is that it's taking too much space. 
What I want to know is, should I upload this folder? I deleted the contents of it and nothing happened on the site.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete this directory. Browsers care only about `CSS` files.

In fact you can compile `SASS` locally and push produced `CSS` only.

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656630/what-are-the-files-in-sass-cache-for), the Sass cache folder is used to speed up compilation.

In production you don't need the folder, only the generated CSS files, **so you're ok to delete it**.